# How to darken the selected song in MPMusicpalyer using iphone sdk?

Tags: ios4, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am using ipod library for my applicatio, But the Song Choice is not real intuitive.  One thing I’ve noticed is that when you tap on a song, it turns light blue.  It’s hard to determine if you tap on it.  If you tap on the song multiple times, it puts it down in the play list multiple times.

How can we overcome these issues? please suggest.

Thanks in advance,
Sekhar. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some people it might be useful to have a song selected multiple times. If you don't want it selected multiple times you could always just scan through the items NSArray and copy the unique ones into a new NSMutableArray.